# Looping through iterrows and replacing null values with predicted values from Model

Tags: python, pandas, knn

I am filling in some missing values `(NaN)` using a predicted value built with a `KNN Regressor Model`.  Now, I'd like to input the predicted values as a new column in the original data frame, keeping the original values for those rows that weren't `NaN`. This will be a brand new column in my data frame which I'll use to build a feature.

I'm using iterrows to loop through the values to build a new column, but I'm getting an error. I've used 2 different ways to isolate the `NaN` values. However, I'm running problems across each method

```
sticker_price_preds = []
features = ['region_x', 'barrons', 'type_x', 'tier_x', 'iclevel_x', 
'exp_instr_pc_2013']

for index, row in data.iterrows():
    val = row['sticker_price_2013']
    if data[data['sticker_price_2013'].isnull()]:
        f = row['region_x', 'barrons', 'type_x', 'tier_x', 'iclevel_x', 
'exp_instr_pc_2013']
        val = knn.predict(f)
    sticker_price_preds.append(val)

data['sticker_price_preds'] = sticker_price_preds
```

AND

```
sticker_price_preds = []
features = ['region_x', 'barrons', 'type_x', 'tier_x', 'iclevel_x', 
'exp_instr_pc_2013']

for index, row in data.iterrows():
    val = row['sticker_price_2013']
    if not val:
        f = row['region_x', 'barrons', 'type_x', 'tier_x', 'iclevel_x', 
'exp_instr_pc_2013']
        val = knn.predict(f)
    sticker_price_preds.append(val)

data['sticker_price_preds'] = sticker_price_preds
```

I'm returning the following error message for the first method:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

For the second method, the NaN rows are remaining empty

Comment: In the second example, change `if not val` to `if np.isnan(val)`. NaN is a special value such that `not np.nan` is `False`.

Comment: Thanks that worked! Seems numpy np.isnan() is the solution. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

A little tough without data to try it out, but if you want a vector solution this might work. Make a column that has the knn.predict values, and then filter the dataframe for np.NaN

```
df['predict'] = knn.predict(features)
```

--

```
data.loc[data['sticker_price_2013'].isna(),'sticker_price_2013'] = data.loc[data['sticker_price_2013'].isna(), 'predict']
```